# Bulk Translate of Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate, textjoin

I want to translate many foreign cities into Turkish.

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2:A100; "en"; "tr")
```

When I run this function for B2:B100, it only translates B2.

Is there any way to translate all of them with one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

googletranslate does not support arrays. you can either hardcode it like:

```
={GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2; "en"; "tr");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(A3; "en"; "tr");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(A4; "en"; "tr");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(A5; "en"; "tr")}
```

or you can try something like:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(TEXTJOIN(". "; 1; A2:A100); "en"; "tr"); "."))))
```

Answer (score 0):

with new functions now possible:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A100; LAMBDA(x; GOOGLETRANSLATE(x; "en"; "tr"))))
```

[image]